# linux command "wc" not exiting when run with execvp

Tags: c, linux, command, exec

by doing `execvp("wc", { "wc", "-c", NULL } );` and then sending text to the process stdin, the process never end it keep waiting for new `stdin`.

in my terminal also doing `wc -c` and then writing text it never get out of the process after hiting enter multiple times only <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> ends but then i don't get the result

Comment: Post your actual code.  Would you tell a automobile mechanic "My car doesn't work.  What's wrong with it?" in a text and expect a real answer?

Comment: what about the terminal

Comment: In a terminal, you need to signal you're dong typing in input with a ctrl-d.

Comment: And in a program, if wc's standard input is the read end of a pipe, you need to close all copies of the write end for it to see end of input.

Comment: solved forgot to close stdin